# .getWidth(), .getHeight() in Java

Tags: java, awt

So I just started learning Java yesterday coming from a different language, and I am reading through my textbook and finding it to be pretty nice so far. However I did an exercise that basically required me to create a new Object use Rectangle and find the area. Below is the working code I came up with.

Now coming from other programming languages I was just toying around with this and did `int area,width,height;`and then it gave me an error saying that I had to use double in order to utilize `.getWidth();, .getHeight()`. I couldn't find anything in my book telling me why I had to make this a double and I started looking online and found this link

Now I found some documentation online where It told me to use double as well, but I'm not really sure why would I need to set these as doubles. Is it because the people who made Java, knew that precision is needed when we are working with coordinates and doing math with widths, heights and coordinates? My book says that it takes more memory to make a `double` variable rather than an `int` ( I come from doing lots of javascript and PHP, so reading on what a `float` and `double` does was something good for me).

I.E. Why do I need to make my `area,height,width` variable doubles in order to use `.getWidth,.getHeight`

```
package keepo;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
public class tuna{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10,20,50,40);
        double area,width,height;
        width = rect.getWidth();
        height = rect.getHeight();
        area = width * height;
        System.out.println("Width is : " + width + "Height is : " + height);
        System.out.println("Area is : " + area);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote, I don't think my question is that bad? I actually did  some research before asking too :/

Comment: thats just how it is I guess,right?

Comment: Don't know how to make classes, I'll get back to you on that soon hopefully :D

Comment: Is that what the import.java.awt.rectangle means?. Just some helper classes the java team made? And now I'm using it?

Comment: Yeah you are using a Rectangle class that java did for awt (window frame work), the `import java.awt.Rectangle`, just let you reference it as `Rectangle`, you could do without import but then you need to do `java.awt.Rectangle rect =   new java.awt.Rectangle(10,20,50,40);`

Comment: I think this is for consistencies sake with shape and rectangle2d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because this is how these methods have been defined in the [java api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html). As you can see under the **modifier and type** column that the methods `getWidth()`, `getHeight()` all return value of type `double`.

Comment: That seems odd though. I understand sometimes precision is important, but in my example at least I wouldnt need to use a double. It seems like using a double is just wasting memory when we could use an int. Odd.

Comment: @cresjoy,  When they made rectangle, they could have chosen to use integers.  And they might have chosen to use double length floating point numbers.   For many cases using integers would be fine.  But there are many cases were integers would not be enough.   So the people who made the clases designed them with doubles.   It's true that if you use the class and only require integers, then you are wasting a bit of space.  But not enough to worry about unless you are planning to make and use millions of them simultaneously.

Comment: Fair enough, I just thought there was some sort of funtionality for the rect object to realize that all its parameters are integers, and so allow you to use the "int" keyword, and if the parameters are doubles you use the double keyword. If you know what I mean. Then again I don't know how developing a language works itself.

Comment: According to [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) It is also worth noting that for decimal values, `double` is generally the default data type.

Comment: I see. When in doubt use doubles I guess haha

Answer (score 1):

Because in this case, you should not use those methods. The AWT class `Rectangle` [does store coordinates as `int`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#field.summary). You can easily read them back as `int`s if that's what you want to do, by accessing the **fields** instead of calling the getter methods:

```
int area, width, height;
width = rect.width; // not getWidth()
height = rect.height; // not getHeight()
area = width * height;
```

The `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods serve zero purpose here, as they will always return the same value as the fields, except as a different type (and you can already assign any `int` value to a `double` anyway, when a `double` is what you want to use).

So why do those two methods (along with `getX()` and `getY()`) exist at all? Because in Java 1.2 the geometry stuff in the API was expanded. People wanted to be able to work with floating-point coordinates, which `Rectangle` cannot do. And the Java maintainers couldn't change the fields of `Rectangle` from `int` to `double` because that would break backwards compatibility with how old code was already using it. So two new classes, [`Rectangle2D.Float`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.Float.html) and [`Rectangle2D.Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.Double.html) were added, which store coordinates as `float`s and `double`s respectively.

But what if you want to work generically with any rectangle, without writing separate code for all the rectangle flavors? A new abstract class, [`Rectangle2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html) was also added, as the superclass of the three rectangle classes. This class is abstract (meaning it cannot be created on its own, as it is incomplete) and it does not store any coordinates itself. It does however, specify a contract that its subclasses follow (meaning that any `Rectangle2D` method is available in all three of its implementations). That includes the `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods that return `double`s, regardless of the actual storage type of the particular rectangle.

Taking the abstraction an extra, perhaps superfluous, level, they also added [`RectangularShape`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/RectangularShape.html) as the superclass of several shapes with rectangular bounds: `Rectangle2D`, `RoundRectangle2D`, `Ellipse2D` and `Arc2D`. That is the class that actually declares the `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods, which all `RectangularShape` subclasses must provide:

```
// What's this shape? A rectangle? An ellipse? Does it use ints? floats? doubles?
RectangularShape something = ......;
// We don't care!
System.out.println("The shape (whatever it is) occupies an area of:");
System.out.println(something.getWidth() + " × " + something.getHeight());
```

So you can call those getter methods on any rectangle (or "rectangular shape") to get its coordinates, but if you know you have a particular shape class, you can/should access its fields directly, as that is simpler, and it gives you the values without converting them to a different type.

P.S. It is a similar story with `Point`, which uses `int` coordinates, but provides `double getX()` and `double getY()` methods, because of the later-added classes `Point2D.Float`, and `Point2D.Double`, and the abstract superclass [`Point2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html).

P.P.S. There is actually a small advantage to using `double` (or `long`) for your rectangle's area, even if your rectangle coordinates are `int`s. Large multiplications could *overflow* the 32-bit range of an `int`, producing the wrong result. If you convert at least one of the values to a larger type, it will cause the multiplication to be done in that larger type, which you can then safely store without overflow:

```
Rectangle big = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1000000, 1000000);
int area = big.width * big.height;
long bigArea = (long)big.width * big.height;
System.out.println(area); // -727379968 (uh oh!)
System.out.println(bigArea); // 1000000000000
```

Comment: Thanks, this is alot to take in, I just started chapter two yesterday, and just learned about variable types but for some reason my book has me drawing rectangles and circles and finding areas already!

Answer (score 0):

[Imran Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/923194/imran-ali) is right.

This is java documentations for `getHeight()` and for `getWidth()` it's same.

> `java.​awt.​Rectangle`
>
> - `public double getHeight()`
>
> Returns the height of the bounding Rectangle in **double** precision
>
> ---
>
> **Returns:**
>   the height of the bounding Rectangle.

But if you want/need to use **int** *instead of* **double**, use following codes for **height** and repeat them for **width** too:

- using `getSize()` method which returns rectangle [**dimension**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html) then use it's fields (`width` and `height`)

  - `int height = rect.getSize().height;`
- using data [**type casting**](http://www.studytonight.com/java/type-casting-in-java)

  - `int height = (int) rect.getHeight();`
  - `int height = (int) rect.getSize().getHeight();`

Answer (score 0):

The `Rectangle.getWidth()` and `Rectangle.getHeight()`methods both return their values with `double` precision, as stated by others. It is easier if you just keep using them, in order to prevent the `Rectangle`'s values from being changed on accident, by simply casting the value to an `int`:

`int width = (int)rect.getWidth()`
and `int height = (int)rect.getHeight()`

Comment: This advice makes zero sense. Even if you were to accidentally change the rectangle by confusing its fields for some other variable in your application, you wouldn't accidentally use its getter method to do so, so you would end up using the getter method only when you didn't want it, and accessing the field only when you didn't want that!